# Android File.renameTo always return false in my test Sony device

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to rename a file to add it extension. I'm detecting the type of the file, and want to append the extension to the file. It all works well, but I have a Sony Xperia Z2 for testing, and something weird happens. In other devices and emulators, works like a charm, but in this one... it's impossible.

It always return false, despite it has write permission in the parent folder, it's the same folder, and it only appends a ".jpg" or ".png" or something like that. As the `File.renameTo` function doesn't gives any error, just throw false, I can't know for sure if it's only me... but I start to believe it's something about how it manage the internal/external storage. The internal storage is actually sdcard0, and the external is sdcard1. Some apps, like ES File Manager, ask about where the root of my sdcard is, so it can rename, move, or copy files in my sdcard. Airdroid ask me to do the same thing. Why is that happening? How can I fix this?

Oh, and I have the pertinent permissions in the manifest, I've been searching a lot for a fix for this thing... and doesn't works in internal storage, as well. I'm totally lost. Here's the function I use to rename the file, if it helps someone... but I think it's a problem of the "internal sdcard" devices, or something.

```
private void setFixed(File f, String ext){
    File parent = f.getParentFile();
    try {
        String name = f.getName();
        String toName = (name+"."+ext).replace(" ", "");
        //Lines that I added just to test. I saw before I call this function that the parent has write permission.
        //Log.i("Pre", parent.getCanonicalPath()+name);
        //Log.i("Post", parent.getCanonicalPath()+toName);
        //File of = new File(parent.getCanonicalPath()+name);
        //File nf = new File(parent.getCanonicalPath()+toName);
        //Log.i("Converted", String.valueOf(of.renameTo(nf)));
        File f1 = new File(parent.getAbsolutePath()+toName);
        boolean success = f.renameTo(f1);
        Log.i("File renamed?", String.valueOf(success));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What Android versions are you testing on?

Comment: 4.4 and 5.1, being 5.1 the emulator (it works there) and my Sony device (where it's the problem...)

Comment: Changes have been made to how apps can access external SD cards ("secondary external storage") between 4.3 and 4.4, and then again between 4.4 and 5.0, see e.g. https://metactrl.com/docs/sdcard-on-kitkat/.

Comment: Ohh... So, now I see why it ask me in other apps. But I think it still isn't the problem, because I can't access the Internal storage either. And my friend tested it with a 4.4 android device... And worked like a charm. Thanks for the info, though!

Comment: `new File(parent.getAbsolutePath()+toName);` may also be causing trouble, if `getAbsolutePath()` does not include a trailing separator. Try `new File(parent, toName);` instead.

Comment: No luck... Do you have more ideas? Thanks!

Comment: it is a wild guess but have you set correct permissions in your manifest to access storage?

Comment: One more thing: Apparently, when the user grants an app access to (a part of) the SD card, this is stored somewhere by the Android system to not bother the user again. Once, I selected the wrong folder and after that could not get the app to work anymore. I had to first clear all app data to be prompted again, alternatively un-installing and re-installing the app. Did you try that?

Comment: @Pooya Do you mean this line?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Yup, I have it. But I also set READ, just to test, but didn't change anything.

Comment: @JimmyB What kind of request do you mean? The one in Android 6.0? What permissions do I have the user to ask for that to work? Now, I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for `renameTo(File)` (click on the method and press ctrl + Q).

> Renames this file to newPath. This operation is supported for both
>   files and directories. Many failures are possible. Some of the more
>   likely failures include: Write permission is required on the
>   directories containing both the source and destination paths. Search
>   permission is required for all parents of both paths. Both paths be on
>   the same mount point. On Android, applications are most likely to hit
>   this restriction when attempting to copy between internal storage and
>   an SD card. Note that this method does not throw IOException on
>   failure. Callers must check the return value.

As you can see, the search permission is required. Ensure that you add this to the manifest.

You also need to change

`File f1 = new File(parent.getAbsolutePath()+toName);`

to

```
File f1 = new File(parent.getAbsolutePath().toString()+ "/" +toName);
```

Comment: `new File(parent.getAbsolutePath().toString()+ "/" +toName);` - Please, don't do that!

Comment: I've already read the doc, but I have write permission in that directory (I tested it, and canWrite() returned true in the parent folder), both paths are in the same folder, and... I don't exactly know what it refers to with "search permission". I can't find it anywhere... but I don't think it's the case, because I tested the only thing I found: GLOBAL_SEARCH permission in the manifest.

Also, the File path it's not the problem. File nf = new File(parent.getCanonicalPath()+toName); <- that gave me a clean path, no errors. @JimmyB can rest know ;)

Comment: That is not good ,there is one more way which you can rename the file.Copy old file to new file with new name and delete that old file.I have wrote this method for years.

Comment: @MehdiJahedManesh I though of that workaround but... I don't think it's the correct approach in this situation. Imagine that I need to move a 1GB file... In the limited storage size we have in smartphones, that could be a big problem.